# Force Powershell to add duplicate values into main report table

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I have a script that creates a Public IPs report. I'm having problem with one VM having two NICs attached to it. My script is designed in a way, that VM name is unique key, upon which all the other data is correlated and assigned to main table. Is there any way to get around this? Here's my script:

```
#Data collection
$PIP = Get-AzPublicIpAddress

$pipOutput = $PIP | ForEach-Object {
[PSCustomObject]@{
"IP Name" = $_.Name
"IP Address" = $_.IpAddress
"Resource Group Name" = $_.ResourceGroupName
"Location" = $_.Location
"VM Name" = ""
"Network Interface" = ""
"Application" = $_.Tag.Application
"Environment" = $_.Tag.Environment
"Role" = $_.Tag.Role
"Decommission" = $_.Tag.Decommission
"Funding" = $_.Tag.Funding
"Provisioning State" = $_.ProvisioningState
"Allocation Method" = $_.PublicIpAllocationMethod
"Version" = $_.PublicIpAddressVersion
"Idle Timeout In Minutes" = $_.IdleTimeoutInMinutes
}
}

$VMs = Get-AzVm -status
$all = @{}
$end = @{}

foreach ($vm in $VMs) {
    $VMNetworkInterfaceSplitToArray = $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.id.Split('/')
    $VMNetworkInterfaceObject = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $VMNetworkInterfaceSplitToArray[$VMNetworkInterfaceSplitToArray.Count - 1]
    try {
        $VMPublicIpSplitToArray = ($VMNetworkInterfaceObject.IpConfigurations.publicipaddress.Id).Split('/')
        $vm_Public_IP = (Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $VMPublicIpSplitToArray[$VMPublicIpSplitToArray.Count - 1]).IpAddress 
    }
    catch {
        $vm_Public_IP = "n/a"
    }

    if($vm_Public_IP -ne "n/a")
    {
    $all.Add($vm_Public_IP,$vm.name)
    $end.Add($vm_Public_IP,$VMNetworkInterfaceObject.name)
    }

    }

foreach ($ipadd in $pipOutput)
{
    if($all.ContainsKey($ipadd."IP Address"))
    {
        $ipadd."VM Name"=$all[$ipadd."IP Address"]
    }
    else
    {
        $ipadd."VM Name"="n/a"
    }
}

foreach ($ipadd in $pipOutput)
{
    if($end.ContainsKey($ipadd."IP Address"))
    {
        $ipadd."Network Interface"=$end[$ipadd."IP Address"]
    }
    else
    {
        $ipadd."Network Interface"="n/a"
    }
}
```

Comment: you run into an error because `$VMNetworkInterfaceObject` can either be a single object or a collection? If yes, include another `foraech`

Comment: stop using hashtables. [*grin*] do your lookup in the main loop - where you build the VM list. right now you are iterating thru the PublicIpAddress list twice ... i would do it all in one pass. ///// i can't give you any details since i have no access to the objects you are working with. [*blush*]

Comment: Purpose of using hashtables is to associate NIC and public ip's with VM name, which I add later to main $pipOutput variable. I was trying to do the same within one PSCustomObject (by parsing these information to the table with 3 columns making public ip an unique key instead of VM name, as hashtable can only have 2 of them), but I wasn't able to do so, because of error: 

Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error: Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition', I suggest you create an array to save all your PSCustomObject.
For example

```
Connect-AzAccount

$PIP = Get-AzPublicIpAddress

$pipOutput = $PIP | ForEach-Object {
[PSCustomObject]@{
"IP Name" = $_.Name
"IP Address" = $_.IpAddress
"Resource Group Name" = $_.ResourceGroupName
"Location" = $_.Location
"VM Name" = ""
"Network Interface" = ""
"Application" = $_.Tag.Application
"Environment" = $_.Tag.Environment
"Role" = $_.Tag.Role
"Decommission" = $_.Tag.Decommission
"Funding" = $_.Tag.Funding
"Provisioning State" = $_.ProvisioningState
"Allocation Method" = $_.PublicIpAllocationMethod
"Version" = $_.PublicIpAddressVersion
"Idle Timeout In Minutes" = $_.IdleTimeoutInMinutes
}
}

$vms =Get-AzVM 
$all =@()
Foreach($vm in $vms){
    
    $VMNetworkInterfaceToArray = $vm.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces.id
     foreach($r in $VMNetworkInterfaceToArray ){
 
        $resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceId $r
        $VMNetworkInterfaceObject=Get-AzNetworkInterface -Name $resource.Name -ResourceGroupName $resource.ResourceGroupName
        try{
        $VMPublicIp=Get-AzResource -ResourceId $VMNetworkInterfaceObject.IpConfigurations.publicipaddress.Id
         $vm_Public_IP = (Get-AzPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $VMPublicIp.ResourceGroupName -Name $VMPublicIp.Name).IpAddress 
         }catch {
            $vm_Public_IP = "n/a"
         }

         if($vm_Public_IP -ne "n/a")
        {
             #create custom object to save the details your need
             $obj= [PSCustomObject]@{"VmName"=$vm.Name
                         "VMPublicIP"=$vm_Public_IP
                         "VMNetworkInterface"=$VMNetworkInterfaceObject.Name
                       }
             # save the object into array
             $all +=$obj

        }
     }
}
Foreach($ipadd in $pipOutput){

   foreach($a in $all){
    
     if($a.VMPublicIP=$ipadd.'IP Address'){
       $ipadd.'VM Name' =$a.VmName
       $ipadd.'Network Interface'=$a.VMNetworkInterface
       
     }else{
     
       $ipadd.'VM Name' ="n/a"
       $ipadd.'Network Interface'="n/a"
     
     }
   
   
   }

}
```

## Update

Please change the script as below

```
Foreach($ipadd in $pipOutput){

   foreach($a in $all){

     if($ipadd.'IP Address'.Equals($a.VMPublicIP)){
     
     $ipadd.'VM Name' =$a.VmName
       $ipadd.'Network Interface'=$a.VMNetworkInterface

     }else{

       $ipadd.'VM Name' ="n/a"
       $ipadd.'Network Interface'="n/a"

     }

   }

}
```

Comment: There is a flaw in your script, as it adds the same VM name and NIC to every Public IP entry. Script collects data properly in this if($vm_Public_IP -ne "n/a") loop, but there's something wrong in this loop: Foreach($ipadd in $pipOutput)

Comment: @lubierzca Could you please describe the error in detail?

Comment: Loop _if($vm_Public_IP -ne "n/a")_ script assigns correct values of VM name and NIC names to Public IPs. _$all_ table looks like this:

Public IP VM NIC
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

When script wants to add these values to the _$pipOputput_ in _Foreach($ipadd in $pipOutput)_ loop, it doesn't add the corresponding values from _$all table_, it adds the same VM name and NIC name to every Public IP entry. Specifically it adds the last VM and NIC entries from _$all_ table, which results in $pipOutput looking like this:

Public IP VM NIC
1 3 3
2 3 3
3 3 3

Comment: Script adds n/a to every Public ID entry for VM name and NIC, except for the last row (for which it adds correct values)

Comment: @lubierzca please try to use ```foreach($ipadd in $pipOutput){
       $ipadd.'VM Name' ="n/a"
       $ipadd.'Network Interface'="n/a"
      
        foreach($a in $all){

             if($ipadd.'IP Address'.Equals($a.VMPublicIP)){
              
                $ipadd.'VM Name' =$a.VmName
               $ipadd.'Network Interface'=$a.VMNetworkInterface
              
               break

             }
             

            }
          
       

    }

$pipOutput | Format-Table```

Comment: It finally worked! Thank you very much for your help.